# can i return a custom result after reviewing a stored procedures' result?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, resultset

I want to return custom values as the values of the rows in case when no rows are fetched by executing the stored procedure - is there a way to do that?

Comment: am i getting you right: you want to set some kind of default return values on sql-level?

Comment: yep, but only if null / empty value / is returned

Comment: can i at least get a specific row if my stored procedure fetches 0 records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if 0 = (select count(*) from tbl where conditions)
    select 'None' as s, 0 as n
else
    select s, n from tbl where conditions
```

If the rows are returned from a procedure, as opposed to a select, execute into a temporary table, then the same excercise. Like this:

```
create table #tmp (s varchar(17), n integer)

insert into #tmp
    execute myproc
```